# Swagger generates string for DateTime

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I have this action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<Agent[]>> Get(DateTime? lastModified = null) {}
```

I can see that the following swagger json is generated using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v4.0.1:

```
"parameters":[{"name":"lastModified","in":"query","required":false,"type":"string","format":"date-time"}]
```

Why is the type `string`?
Shouldn't it be `DateTime`?

Comment: theres no `Date` type in JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI defines the following basic types: string,number,integer,boolean,array,object.There's no DateTime.

The `string` type includes dates and files and the `date-time` format is one of string formats.

Refer to

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

https://swagger.io/specification/#dataTypes