# How does swagger present the DateTime type as having no nested properties?

Tags: c#, http, swagger

I was wondering how we could make a class/struct appear to be a value type, rather than have multiple nested properties using C#/.NET Core and Swagger

For example, the image shows the DateTime struct be presented as "date": "20022-12-18T13:28:42.409Z"

[image: swagger]

I have tried to replicate this presentation with the other properties in the attached image by using classes, structs with various public or private properties. My guess would be something to do with either Swagger configuration or operator overloads.

Thanks.

Comment: This is standard json serializer, If you overwrite it in code you can serialize it in unix-time ticks for example, or in other non-UTC format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger generates string for DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683614/swagger-generates-string-for-datetime)